# How do you call someone who is looking for the job? As a hustler person

Tags: meaning, word-choice, word-request

Need to know this cause it's disturbing my brain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Job seeker" is a very common term in English for such a person. Note that in older English "hustler" meant someone who was very active and thorough at something, but has fallen out of use now.